# Technique for debugging Three.js

Tags: javascript, debugging, three.js, source-maps

I have a Three.js page that I'd like to update from r42 to r55. A fair amount of the API has changed in that time.

Some of these changes were straightforward, but now I'm stuck on some gnarly details of the `JSONLoader`, for which the format has changed from JavaScript to JSON and possibly other changes are causing it to fail. An `undefined` value is tripping up the API somewhere internally, and I can't tell what the issue is because the top few layers of the stack are in minified code.

What technique works best for getting the full source here? Are there [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) available?

I tried swapping the `three.min.js` file for [`Three.js`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/Three.js), however the minified file contains many other files too. I don't like the idea of having to load all those files into my workspace and reference each of them just to debug a single issue for a minute.

Is there a single file that contains the non-minified equivalent of `three.min.js`? Is there another approach that would work just as well?

---

**EDIT** So I'm cloning the three.js repo to get the source files, and will end up with a bunch of HTML like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="three.js/src/Three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="three.js/src/core/Object3D.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="three.js/src/core/Geometry.js"></script>
...
```

The repo is ~200MB and is taking an age to clone. There's no way to do partial clones with Git, apparently.

There has to be an easier way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually that is what I do when I want to debug my code. Swap out three.min.js and put in three.js. The minified version contains the same code.

The non-minified version of the file is under version control:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/build

Comment: Hi there. Where did you find the three.js file? The [version of that file from the repository](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/Three.js) only contains a fraction of the code, so you'd have to also reference a dozen or so other .js files too.

Comment: in the build directory https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/build. You shouldnt be using the src directory. The code you have above should be replaced by <script type="text/javascript" src="three.js/build/three.js"></script> (all lines should be removed).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this file was in there. Much easier!

Answer (score 2):

1. use non-minified builds
2. look at the commented out debugging points already present in three.js (i.e. console.log)
3. 'use strict' if not already
4. add more console.log/debugs